# Recursively find every first file at each branch of a directory tree

Tags: find, hash

Consider the following directory listing:

```
/a/1
/a/2
/a/3
/b/1
/b/2
/b/3/a
/b/3/b
/c/a.whatever
/c/b
/c/c
```

I want a command that will find the first (alphanumeric sort) file in each directory (inc nested) and deliver the following output:

```
/a/1
/b/1
/b/3/a
/c/a.whatever
```

This seems like a job for `find` but I'm running low on coffee. Release the Ninjas!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution - should work with spaces in the paths

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'find "{}" -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | head -n 1' ";"
```

On a side note, I discovered that `ls` lacks the options to output the full paths, and to list just files (not dirs) :(

Comment: I agree. At first I got stuck with ls, too. It sadly does not provide a usable output for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Using the benefits of **awk** I came up with this:

```
find -type d | awk '{print "find "$0" -type f | head -1"}' | sh | uniq
```

`uniq` becomes necessary because find searches the subdirectories...probably could get around that with an additional find argument somehow.

**edit**
version without uniq

```
find -type d | awk '{print "find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -1"}' | sh
```

Note that you can easily adjust the number of printed files per directory. To sort the files beforehand use:

```
find -type d | awk '{print "find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | head -1"}' | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Well with a bit of poking, my own Ninja skills recuperated slightly and came up with this steamer:

```
find -type d | xargs -I{} bash -c "find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | head -1" | sort
```

Not the most elegant of filesystem queries but it outputs what I'd expect.

Comment: It is funny how all 3 answers at last finalize in calling a shell with literally the same input command :D